# Contact form Emails are not working in magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, transactional-mail

I am not receiving any emails from the contact form. SMTP details are correct, I am able to receive sales emails.

Checked in the source but could not figure it out.

By the way I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and theme is ultimo.

Comment: 1. First check whether your server supports to send mail
2. If yes, please try installing http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html in magento

Comment: Obvious issue might be that the incorrect recipient mail is set in the backend. Check under System / configuration what email is set to receive emails. Without any concrete errors there is little we can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

The contact controller can be found under `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php` and the code responsible for handling this function is under the `postAction()` method:

```
if ($error) {
    throw new Exception();
}
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
/* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
$mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
    ->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
        null,
        array('data' => $postObject)
    );
if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

As you can see, if there is an error, it should throw an exception. Check the contents of your logs (`var/log/system.log` & `var/log/exception.log`) after trying to submit a contact form.

If you don't find anything in these logs, nor anything generated within the `var/report` directory, then you need to do some additional diagnostics.

You can start by doing some in-line diagnostics, for example:

```
echo "Triggered";die();
```

within this method to see whether the submission is even reaching the method. Make sure you perform these diagnostics within a staging environment and revert any core changes made to ensure upgradeability in future.